# using comparators as embedded classes, the mother class (initialized in clone ) fields are not visible in the compare method

Tags: java, clone, inner-classes, comparator

I have developed a server-to-server protocol called CCMN and different drop policies for the messages cached by each server. The PEERSIM simulator creates a template node with the CCMN protocol and then clones this template node.

The CCMN class includes different data structures maintaining the states required to implement the drop policies. For instance, *Pmap* resolves a content identifier to a content object, and *freq* a content identifier to the number of times a content object has been used.

```
public HashMap <String, Content> Pmap;
public HashMap<String, Integer> freq;
```

The initialization of these data structures is done in the clone method of CCMN. In order to support the drop policies, I use a priorityQueue initialized with a comparator corresponding to the policy to use. In the clone method:

```
if(dp.equals(DroppingPolicy.LFU)){
```

lfu less_frequent=new lfu();
  av.raw_drop=new PriorityQueue(1, less_frequent);
 }
The comparator are declared as follows:

```
public class lfu implements Comparator<String> {
```

public int compare(String s0, String s1) {
   if(freq.get(s0) > freq.get(s1)) return 1;
   else if(freq.get(s0) < freq.get(s1)) return -1;
   else return 0;
  }
 }

**The problem is that** I get a NullPointerException exception when i call :

```
raw_drop.add(ct.getID());
```

By debugging, I found that the add works for the first element, but the exception occurs when a second element is added. I traced the exception to the compare method, by checking the variables I find that the *freq* variable (and the other variables initialized in the clone method) equals *null*, while the variables defined in the constructor are well defined.

Moreover, I check that *freq* is well initialized before the *add* call.

I guess that there is a problem between the definition of the comparators as embedded classes and the *clone* method.

Any help is welcome.

Regards, Mohamed

Comment: Sorry man for a fairly related comment, but why do you use such weird comparator? Isn't it easier to write
            return freq.get(s0).compareTo(freq.get(s1));
?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but this will not change anything to the problem, because the problem is that freq is not initialized in the compare method...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. In fact, the nested comparators referenced the template instance instead of the cloned instance. I add a counter so that the first time, the method the instruction `raw_drop.add(ct.getID())` belongs to, is called  the priorityQueue used by the instance is initialized in order to have the right initialization.